# Amazon Dynamo Like Database using Akka Cluster

Tags: akka, replication, amazon-dynamodb, akka-cluster, consistent-hashing

I am trying to build a Dynamo Like Database using Akka

Hints are given in the Akka Cluster specification here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/cluster/cluster.html

[image]

How to implement the read write replicas ?

I have implemented the Single System data broker and the repo is here https://github.com/pamu/AkkaDynoDB

Comment: Hi... are you still thinking of working on it ? Or of you have left it, what was the reason ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh not working on it

Comment: Do you have links for 2015'ish literature on dynamodb ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Ping me if you have info on it

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh you can contribute as well . If you like it :)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I would like to start and would like to take it to a point where others can use it. Need help. If you have ideas on architecture and other stuff. You are welcome to contact me and also contribute if it looks good to you.